# how to do dynamic port mapping on fargate containers. and map host port 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, port, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to do dynamic host mapping to fargate containers. when I select **awsvpc** for **fargate** container I'm unable to do dynamic port mapping because there is not host port mapping section given in the containers definition section.
I have mapped my server port on it but not able to make `host port ->0`. host port it the same as the server port.